# An idiom opposite to "every dog has its day"

Tags: phrase-request

I'm looking for an idiom that means: ***There will come a time in everyone's life when they tumble down, or experience a hard time***. Something you'd say to a smug but successful  person who laughs at your misery.

Comment: There are many quotes that include "on your way back down". For example, Be careful who you kick on your way up. You'll see them again on your way back down.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're asking two different things.  There's a general expression to indicate that everyone experiences some misery in their lives, and then there's an expression you'd use as a *comeback* to the person you mention above.

As a comeback:

> What goes up, must come down.

As a general philosophy:

> Into every life some rain must fall.

Comment: "Every silver lining has a cloud."

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good moment for "pride comes before a fall" to me. This is often rendered as pride cometh before a fall to sound extra old timey and clever.

The basic meaning if it's not obvious is that a person who is too over confident will often make a mistake or run into harder times which brings them back down with a metaphorical bump.